# Fixed Div on top of the page with logo on the right and navigation links on the left

Tags: html, css

I am having some troubles with my fixed div. 
I want to have my logo indented to the right so it would be somewhat ind the middle and my navigation links indented to left. but once i resize my web browser window to the the left, the links go over the logo, and vice versa.

is there any way i can have a fixed div and have my logo and links maintain same position when resizing? or when i resize they shift together to whatever side.

http://jsfiddle.net/marrto/Dtz2C/

```
<div id="container">
<div id="nav"> <div>
  <spanl> 
         <a href="index.html"> LOGO IMAGE </a>
  </spanl>
  </div> 

<div>
<spantr>
    <ul>
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Merchandise</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
</ul>
</spantr>
</div>
```

```
#nav {
position:fixed;
left:0px;
top:0px;
height:55px;
width:100%;
background:#999;
}

#container div spanl{
position:absolute;
top:0px;
left:500px;;
padding: 1em;



 }
 #container div spanr{
position:absolute;
top:0px;
right:500px;
padding: 1em;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;

 }


ul {
 overflow: visible;
 list-style-type: none;

 }

li {
height: 15px;
float: left;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-top: -10px;
 border-right: 1px solid #aaa;
padding: 0 10px;

}

li:last-child {
border-right: none;
}
```

Comment: I suggest you to use float than postion. That will solve your issue.

Comment: You seem to be making up your own elements ` <spanl>`, `<spantr>`. Don't do that..it will cause all sorts of issues. Floats & source order is something you should be looking into. http://learnlayout.com/

Comment: Twitters website is a good example. it has a fixed top bar, and the links and search bar are indented to the middle. and when you resize the the browser window the content just shifts in sync. that what i would like to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

How about this? I used `float` left on the nav and right on the logo

http://jsfiddle.net/Dtz2C/4/